# Geofire search in a very large firebase database android

Tags: firebase, indexing, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

what I'm trying to build is a map that support millions of markers. I worked on everything from clustering markers to load only visible markers using geoquery.atLocation and here it is my problem : geofire take a long time to search in a millions of data. If the app doen't crash in this case. I can change the structure of the database to resolve the problem but this  is going to create a lot of  issue for me. So is there any trick that make geofire search in very large database to support millions.

Comment: You may use the firebase analytics or run the adhoc queries in bigquery console.

Comment: Or you can export the data to Google cloud and do the analytics locally too if you have any commodity cluster

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `.indexOn` field `g`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "locations": {
      ".indexOn": "g"
    }
  }
}
```

when running `GeoQuery` with a circular radius, this will load a little more than it would, when querying with rectangular boundaries - while this is not being supported, therefore it is not really avoidable.